# Is there any way to hide AWS lambda code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to publish my application and provide lambdas to other so that I want that on exporting the lambda package no one can get the lambda code.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an API Gateway which will connect the application to your Lambda code. Give that API endpoint URL to the others and they will call your Lambda function through that. This way they cannot know what's going on in your Lambda code.

Comment: Thanks, but I need that the lambda get deployed on my client's AWS instance. I don't want to create any connection between my AWS instance to Customer's AWS instance.

Comment: i don't know it will work or not but you can try to convert all your code to exe file, then make a main script which will call this exe file. Upload whole zip file to AWS Lambda.

Comment: @sid8491 How would you run an exe file on AWS Lambda?

Comment: @dashmug, i'm not sure, i was thinking putting everything including exe file and python files into a zip file, upload it to lambda, this way exe file will be in same path as main python file and somehow we can invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal way is to use API gateway and use it as trigger for your Lambda and share that endpoint to the users.

However if you don't want that you should probably consider cross account access with cross account role (give permission to execute just the Lamnda you want to expose & setup trust relationship) . Let them assume this role and call this lambda.